# Steam>Warning: failed to init SDL thread priority manager: SDL not found — Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, steam

### Following the documentation of Valve to install [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD)

I'm attempting to both install SteamCMD and run a gaming server on an EC2 instance using Amazon Linux 2 or Redhat.

**Steps taken (after creating a user and granting it sudo right permissions):**

- sudo yum install steamcmd
- sudo yum install glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686
- su - user
- mkdir ~/Steam && cd ~/Steam
- curl -sqL "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf -
- ./steamcmd.sh

**Problem that occurs:**

```
Steam>Warning: failed to init SDL thread priority manager: SDL not found
```

[I then search for SDL packages, and have tried each one, but with no success.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyAwW.png)

Answer (score 1):

The 32 bit `SDL` library would be provided by the `SDL.i686` package:

```
yum install SDL.i686
```

If you also need the development libraries:

```
yum install SDL-devel.i686
```